# webrtc onicecandidate not called on opera browser

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have a problem, my onicecandidate event is not being fired in opera browser, here is my code

I tried me getUserMedia added the stream to RTCPeerConnection in different ways (via addStream and addTrack), set offerToReceiveAudio and offerToReceiveVideo, none of this helped

CODE

```
const RTCPeerConnection =  window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
const RTCSessionDescription = window.RTCSessionDescription || window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.RTCSessionDescription;
const RTCIceCandidate = window.mozRTCIceCandidate || window.RTCIceCandidate;

const mediaConstraints = {
    offerToReceiveAudio: true,
    offerToReceiveVideo: false
}

const options = {
    iceServers: [
        {
          urls: 'turn:74.11.232.11:3478',
          credential: 'password',
          username: 'username'
        }
    ],
};

function getUserMedia(callback) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: false
    }).then(callback);
}

getUserMedia((stream) => {
     localStream = stream

     localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false

     WebRtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(options)

     WebRtcPeerConnection.addStream(stream)

     WebRtcPeerConnection.createOffer(mediaConstraints).then((offer) => {
         console.log(offer.sdp)
         WebRtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
         WebRtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = onRoomIceCandidate
         onRoomOffer(null, offer)
     });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was to declare the constant RTCPeerConnection, as I understood in Opera browser RTCPeerConnection is a global class (which is not in window.RTCPeerConnection, etc.)
I needed to replace this line

`const RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;`

to this

`const RTCPeerConnection = RTCPeerConnection || window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;`